# Where is the selected Python interpreter path stored in Visual Studio Code (workspace)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-poetry

I am using Visual Studio Code for my Python development, and I can select the Python interpreter through the UI by using cmd + shift + p and then choosing Python: Select interpreter.

I've checked the `<project>/.vscode/settings.json` file, but I couldn't find the information about the selected Python interpreter there (it's actually empty `{}`). Can someone please guide me on where Visual Studio Code stores the information about the selected Python interpreter? I would like to know the location of this setting, as I'm working with multiple projects in a monorepo, and the interpreter/venv seems to be automatically activated whenever I open the terminal. But sometimes the wrong one is picked. Pretty annoying

Your help is much appreciated!